# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.createCriteriaDelete()Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaDelete;

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria

I am trying to do a delete using criteria query.
But it seems fine but shows error during runtime.
I get an error as seen below:

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.createCriteriaDelete(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaDelete;

My code is given below.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = faqentityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaDelete<Wr3HanbaiChik> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(Wr3HanbaiChik.class);
Root e = delete.from(Wr3HanbaiChik.class);
delete.where(cb.equal((e.get("fkenCd")), 2));
faqentityManager.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
```

The same entity manager is working for criteria query select. So the problem is not in the entity manager.
Also the error is shown only on

```
CriteriaDelete<Wr3HanbaiChik> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(Wr3HanbaiChik.class);
```

Comment: I am using maven and JPA 2.1

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Add new information as an edit to your original question, not in a comment. Code and XML are not appropriate for comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is (most probably) caused by your dependencies - you did not include hibernate-core, which means that there is no available implementation to call `createCriteriaDelete` on.